# how to prove the continuity of the Taylor $f^{(n)}(\xi(x))$?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

let $f(x)=f(x_{0})+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\cdots+\frac{f^{(n)}(\xi(x))}{n!}(x-x_{0})^{n}$

I need to prove that $x \mapsto f^{(n)}(\xi(x))$ is continuous if $f\in C^n[x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta]$ or in other words if $f$ is $n$ times differentiable.

A function is continuous if $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}f(x)=f(x_0)$. I know that $f$ must be continuous, because it is n times differentiable. However when we reveal $f^{(n)}(\xi(x))$ we get that

$f^{(n)}(\xi(x))=\frac{(f(x)-f(x_{0})-f'(x_0)(x-x_{0})-\frac{f''(x_0)(x-x_{0})^{2}}{2}-\cdots-f^{(n-1)}(x_0)\frac{(x-x_0)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!})n!}{(x-x_{0})^{n}}$

When we take this to the limit we get

$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{(f(x)-f(x_{0})-f'(x_0)(x-x_{0})-\frac{f''(x_0)(x-x_{0})^{2}}{2}-\cdots-f^{(n-1)}(x_0)\frac{(x-x_0)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!})n!}{(x-x_{0})^{n}}$ and from there a $\frac{0}{0}$ uncertainty.

This is the extent to which I think I have correctly solved this exercise, but now I (this is how I must solve it) must apply the L'Hospital rule. I am not sure what is the correct way to go about this, but I'll give what I think might be true.

If we differentiate both the numerator and the denominator once we get:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{(f'(x)-0-f'(x_0)-f''(x_0)(x-x_0)-\cdots-f^{(n-1)}(x_0)\frac{(x-x_0)^{n-2}}{(n-2)!})n!}{n(x-x_0)^{n-1}}$

Assuming this is even correct, I have no idea where to go from here. If at all possible, please provide explanations. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you apply the L'Hospital rule not once but $(n-1)$ times?

Comment: I think I get $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x)-f^{(n-1)}(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}$. I'm not sure what will come of this now. Is it correct that for the nth differential I get $\frac{f^{(n)}(x)-f^{(n}(x_{0}}{(x-x_{0})'}$ So $x_{0}^{'}$ will be zero, $x$ will be $1$ and I get $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\{f^{n}(x)$. So therefore it will be close to $f(\xi(x))$ but I don't know how to get continuity from there.

Comment: The limit you get is precisely $f^{(n)}(x_0)$. Thus if you define $\xi(x)$ at $x=x_0$ to be $x_0$, then $f^{(n)}(\xi(x))$ will be continuous. The point is that you could define $\xi(x_0)$ to be anything as long as it is in the domain of $f^{(n)}$, but there is only one definition that makes $f^{(n)}(\xi(x))$ continuous near $x_0$.

Comment: And may I ask which definition is that?

Comment: The one I just gave in the second sentence.